# LARAVEL : http removed from url when using URL HELPER method

Tags: php, laravel, http, url, helper

I m new to laravel, I cloned a laravel project from git that works fine for my team but not me..... when using this line (as an example)

[image]

it gives me
[image]

I ll be thankful if someone know why the url() helper methods delete the http from the url

Comment: What is `config('app.url')` set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by adding APP_SCHEMA=http to my .env file